# Run a JavaScript code whenever I enter any webpage

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I want to run a JavaScript code whenever I enter any webpage of any website without any extension. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

write your inside load--

```
window.onload=function() { 
   alert ('hello world');
};
```

or

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: i want to load automatically in any website. not i my website by console .